# Asp.net webform, jquery

Tags: ajax, webforms

I’m working on a project of estimation for my office. I'm using Ajax Autocomplete in Visual Studio 2017. The following code isn’t working in an ASP.Net WebForms project.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTencongtac1" runat="server" CssClass="textboxdinhdang" placeholder="Nhập tên công tác"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
                                                TargetControlID="txtTencongtac1" ServicePath="~/website/admin/SoblHandler.ashx" ServiceMethod="ProcessRequest" EnableCaching="true" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                                                CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" >

    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

.ASHX file here:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        { testalldatabaseEntities _db = new testalldatabaseEntities();
            string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
            List<string> listSoBl = new List<string>();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqltestalldatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSOBL", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@term",
                    Value = term
                });
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    listSoBl.Add(rdr["SOBL"].ToString());
                }


            }
            //var item = _db.ChiTietBangGias.Where(x => x.MaCongTac.Contains(term)).Take(10);
            //    foreach(var item1 in item)
            //    {
            //        listSoBl.Add(item1.MaBangGia.ToString());
            //    }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listSoBl));
        }
```

'[event here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsWyI.png)''1 row 1 character'